# asp:ListBox stutter on click inside chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have 2 `asp:ListBox` controls inside a table (side by side) that inside a `ModalPopUpExtender`, and on every click inside those listBoxes in Chrome browser both make a stutter like it is redrawn on screen. (This behavior only happens in Chrome, tested as well with IE9, Safari and Firefox).

Code:

```
<tr id="Tr1">
    <td>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxAvailableChannels" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="500px"
            DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceAvailableChannels" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"
            AutoPostBack="True"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceAvailableChannels" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAvailableChannelList"
            TypeName="PlayerDataProvider"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonAddChannel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Icons/Arrows/right.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonRemoveChannel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Icons/Arrows/left.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxPlayerChannels" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="500px"
            DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourcePlayerChannels" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"
            AutoPostBack="True"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourcePlayerChannels" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetPlayerChannelList"
            TypeName="PlayerDataProvider">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="p_playerId" SessionField="SelectedPlayerId"
                    Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Using** : Latest AjaxControlToolkit and .NET 4

What is the cause for the stutter and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `AutoPostBack="True"` solved it.